# Invoke method on SQLite connection in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web app with Flask-SQLAlchemy backed by a SQLite database. I need to call a method ([`create_collation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_collation)) right after connecting. Without the SQLAlchemy framework, I can do that like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
conn.create_collation('my_collate', my_collate)
# ... go on and do fancy "order_by" stuff.
```

How do I do that in Flask-SQLAlchemy? Based on the [API](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/) I was thinking of the following, but I get `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'create_collation'`.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def create_engine(self, sa_url, engine_opts):
        engine = super().create_engine(sa_url, engine_opts)
        engine.create_collation('my_collate', self.my_collate)
        return engine

    @staticmethod
    def my_collate(string1, string2):
        return string1.locateCompare(string2)
```

Following the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html) I think I need to get the connection rather than the engine. But I can't find out how.

Also, where should this go specifically in Flask-SQLAlchemy? What part ultimately "connect"s, and how do I tune into that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has an [Events API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/event.html) that allows you to create a function that will be called whenever the connection pool creates a new connection:

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool

@listens_for(Pool, "connect")
def my_on_connect(dbapi_con, connection_record):
    dbapi_con.create_collation('my_collate', my_collate)
```